# Is there real life convergence to a perfect collection of questions?

Tags: discussion, scope

#### Utopia

I really like the conceptual idea of building a perfect collection of questions and answers for a topic.

Of course, that is an utopia - a motivating one, if you ask me.

The idealized life of a Stack Exchange site would be like this:

The vision is to collect all questions with best answers for its topic.
In reality, "all" is defined by the limits of the topic, and by a threshold of relevance inside this topic.

(Let's assume the topic does not evolve over time, so there are no new questions)

There are some aspects to optimize on the way to perfection:

- Increase count of good questions - on topic, and interesting enough
- Keep count of bad questions low - by closing, by publishing a well-defined topic definition
- Increase count of answered questions/accepted answers

I think the first item is the most interesting: How can a topic be covered completely (in a reasonable approximation)? 
To get the best answers, the site would need to attract experts of the topic.

#### What's the reality?

I'm wondering whether there are Stack Exchange sites that show indications of converging to this idealized state. 
Or are there signs of divergence?

Stack Overflow is the oldest site, so it's surely interesting in this regard - but it may also be different in some way; I mostly use other sites, so I do not know much about its development and current state.
Other sites are younger, but they also have more focussed topics, and they seem to have quite some differences in how they develop.